# Define MYSQL query according to values sent from another page

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am trying to set a MYSQL query based on the presence (or absence) of values sent across from a parent page via the URL. The variables are the following:

```
        $startdate = $_GET["selectstartdate"];
        $enddate = $_GET["selectenddate"];
        $ensemble = $_GET["selectensemble"];
        $venue = $_GET["selectvenue"];
        $city = $_GET["selectcity"];
```

The first two will ALWAYS be non-NULL, but the remaining three have a default value of NULL, which may or may not be redefined on the parent page. So, what I need to do is to restructure my SQL query, according to which of these variables I receive.

IF only the first two variables are sent (and all others are NULL), then the following query is correct:

```
        $sql = "SELECT Concert.date, Ensemble.long_name, Concert.title, ensemble_web, Concert.info, Concert.repertoire, Venue.name, venue_web, Venue.address, Venue.city, Venue.map 
                FROM Concert, Ensemble, Venue
                WHERE Concert.ensemble_id = Ensemble.id AND Concert.venue_id = Venue.id
                AND Concert.date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
```

However, if for example $ensemble is not NULL, then I would need an extra line added to my query:

```
                AND Ensemble.short_name='$ensemble';
```

Similarly, if $venue is not NULL, then I would need:

```
                AND Venue.name='$venue';
```

...and, of course, if $city is not NULL, then I would need:

```
                AND Venue.city='$city';
```

I am really what the best way to go about this is. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection, and you can not guarantee that the first two ALWAYS will be non-NULL, because anyone could modify the get parameters.

Comment: Janne: I know, but the information is in no way sensitive, so security in this case is not a major concern.

Comment: What about an attacker dropping all tables, and emptying the database?

Comment: I thought that since the default username & p/w has no privileges other than reading information, that nothing could be edited ..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer to manage your where conditions in simpler way:

```
<?php
// note that this mysqli_real_escape_string will prevent sql injection and $con is your connection variable
$startdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["selectstartdate"]);
$enddate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["selectenddate"]);
$ensemble = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["selectensemble"]);
$venue = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["selectvenue"]);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["selectcity"]);


$sql = "SELECT Concert.date, Ensemble.long_name, Concert.title, ensemble_web, Concert.info, Concert.repertoire, Venue.name, venue_web, Venue.address, Venue.city, Venue.map 
        FROM Concert, Ensemble, Venue
        WHERE Concert.ensemble_id = Ensemble.id AND Concert.venue_id = Venue.id
        AND Concert.date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'";
$where_clause = ["Concert.ensemble_id = Ensemble.id", "Concert.venue_id = Venue.id", "Concert.date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'"];

if(!empty($ensemble)) {
    $where_clause[] = "Ensemble.short_name='$ensemble'";
}

if(!empty($venue)) {
    $where_clause[] = "Venue.name='$venue'";
}

if(!empty($city)) {
    $where_clause[] = "Venue.city='$city'";
}

$sql .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where_clause);
```

Comment: Please note that this code is susceptible to SQL injection, and could give an attacker full access to the database.

Comment: @paul it would be great if you accept it as a answer

Comment: @JanneKlouman as per your point I have added code that prevents sql injection, please check